# iTunes Connect Can't Add iTunes Connect Team Member With Yahoo Email

Tags: ios, email, app-store-connect

Right now, I'm trying to add someone on my iTunes connect team so I can make him an internal tester for my app, but the person who wants to test it has a yahoo email associated with his Apple ID. I tried doing the usual routine

friendEmail+whatever@yahoo.com

But this only seems to work for gmail accounts. Is there a way to get past this? I tried adding his actual email without the + sign and letters, but it says the email is already associated with an iTunes Connect user.

Any help or advice would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: To be eligible to become internal tester, a user must be part of your iTunes connect team with Admin, Legal or Technical role. And most important, you must be registered with iTunes.

Comment: Yeah, I'm trying to add him on my iTunes connect team so I can make him an internal tester. This is where I'm experiencing the problem. I'll edit my question so no one else gets confused about this.